# Mostrar menu widget en panel administracion Wordpress ACF

Tags: wordpress

estoy trabajando una web utilizando wordpress y ACF(advanced custom field). Mi problema es que quiero insertar widget, pero la pestaña de widget está oculta en el menú de wordpress. Supongo que algún archivo debe estar bloqueando su visualización.

¿Cómo hago para que aparezca esa pestaña?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un codigo del functions_limpiar.php que creo que puede tener algo que ver... no estoy seguro.

```
function quitar_widgets_escritorio() {
global $wp_meta_boxes;
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['wp_welcome_panel']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
  }
   add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'quitar_widgets_escritorio' );

 function my_function_admin_bar(){
return false;
    }
   add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no tengas registrada ninguna sidebar.

Probá con el código de ejemplo: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que agregar en tu archivo **functions.php** de tu tema actual.

```
function quitar_widgets_escritorio() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['wp_welcome_panel']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'quitar_widgets_escritorio');

add_action( 'admin_head', 'cn_admin_customize' );
function cn_admin_customize() { ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #welcome-panel, #menu-posts, #menu-media, #menu-links, #menu-pages, #menu-comments, #menu-appearance, #menu-plugins, #menu-users, #menu-tools, #menu-settings {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php }
```

Acabo de probar en mi maquina con un sitio y me funciono.